# TextInputEditText is not showing the typed text/number when typing

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I have to create a form in my application and i used **com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText**. the same is worked earlier but now when type a number or text in my edittext field it is not displaying what i am typing but after remove focus from that particular text field it shows the typed text.
Same way if i delete text also it affected only when i remove focus from the edittext. i couldn't get any error when typing also the some another edittext is working fine in the same form.
When i test the same in multiple devices i got to know tha The same edittext is working fine in API 22 emulator and the problem is API 26 onwards.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/product_stockquantity_input"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/product_stockquntity_edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_red"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:hint="@string/product_stock_quantity"
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>



implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

this is the edittext i have used. please help me to solve the issue. thanks in advance.

[screen shot of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqQAE.jpg)

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be in the layout

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti if it is not in layout what are the other possibilities?

Comment: Do you have some listener? What about your app theme?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar",  and i have two spinner onItemselected in my activity and i have updated my form screenshot

Comment: @developer do you solved this issue?  Becoz me too facing same pbm